# Eigenvalue of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

So here is the question:

> Suppose $A$ is an orthogonal matrix with $\det(A)=-1$, prove $A$ has an eigenvalue $-1$.

Here is my solution, since
$$\begin{split}
&\hspace{0.75cm} Ax=\lambda x\\&\Rightarrow A^\text TAx=A^\text T\lambda x\\&\Rightarrow(A^\text TA-A^\text T\lambda )x=\theta
\end{split}$$
so $$\begin{split}
&\hspace{0.75cm} A^\text TA=\lambda A^\text T\\&\Rightarrow \det(A^\text TA)=\det(\lambda A^\text T)=\lambda^n\det(A^\text T)=-\lambda^n
\end{split}$$
and given $A$ orthogonal, we have
$$\det(A^\text TA)=\det(I)=1$$
so
$$-\lambda^n=1\Rightarrow\lambda=i\;\;\text{or}\;\;\lambda=-1$$
and now I'm stuck, how to I prove $A$ also has an eigenvalue $-1$ when $n$ is even?

Comment: It occurs to me that I didn't actually use the condition that $A$ is orthogonal, since if you replace all $A^\text T$s with $A^{-1}$, the equalities still hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\det(A+I)= \det(A+AA^T)= \det(A(I+A^T))= \det(A) \cdot \det(I+A^T)$$

$$=- \det(I+A)^T= - \det(A+I).$$